# C# Treeview with stored procedure

Tags: c#, treeview, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I would fill a treeview from a stored procedure.

The procedure return a series with its seasons and episodes.

```
program_id  program_header_id   title
1           Null                Game of Thrones
2           1                   Saison 1
3           1                   Saison 2
4           1                   Saison 3
5           2                   Episode 1
6           2                   Episode 2
7           2                   Episode 3
8           2                   Episode 4
9           3                   Episode 1
10          3                   Episode 2
11          4                   Episode 1
```

I would like to see this in a treeview

```
-   Game of Thrones
    -   Saison 1
        -   Episode 1
        -   Episode 2
        -   Episode 3
        -   Episode 4
    -   Saison 2
        -   Episode 1
        -   Episode 2
    -   Saison 3
        -   Episode 1
```

Here's my code to fill the treeview

```
SqlCommand cmd;
cmd = new SqlCommand("S_fiction_program_search_v3", mycon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DataTable dt = new DataTable("treeProgram");
SqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dataAdp.Fill(dt);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Relations.Add("rsParentChild", ds.Tables["treeProgram"].Columns["program_id"], ds.Tables["treeProgram"].Columns["program_header_id"]);
tvMain.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["treeProgram"].DefaultView;
```

And the xaml :

```
<TreeView Name="tvMain" Grid.Row="2">
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding rsParentChild}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding original_title}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

For now, the treeview is filled like this:

```
-   Game of Thrones
        -   Saison 1
            -   Episode 1
            -   Episode 2
            -   Episode 3
            -   Episode 4
        -   Saison 2
            -   Episode 1
            -   Episode 2
        -   Saison 3
            -   Episode 1
-   Saison 1
    -   Episode 1
    -   Episode 2
    -   Episode 3
    -   Episode 4
-   Saison 2
    -   Episode 1
    -   Episode 2
-   Saison 3
-   Episode 1
-   Episode 1
-   Episode 2
-   Episode 3
-   Episode 4
-   Episode 1
-   Episode 2
-   Episode 1
```

The treeview duplicates all data .... :-(
Do you have an idea ?

Comment: It's just a vague conjecture, but if you have set in the Designer already the DataSet manually and then do it secondly with code, it might occur such a problem.

Comment: Your seasons and episodes are still in `rsParentChild`.  Through the `ds.Relations` you get the right tree, but this does not prevent you seasons and episodes be displayed in the main tree. I konw nothing about `DataSets` and `DataTables` so I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

```
SqlCommand cmd;
cmd = new SqlCommand("S_fiction_program_search_v3", mycon);
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
DataTable dt = new DataTable("treeProgram");
SqlDataAdapter dataAdp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
dataAdp.Fill(dt);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.Tables.Add(dt);
ds.Relations.Add("rsParentChild", ds.Tables["treeProgram"].Columns["program_id"], ds.Tables["treeProgram"].Columns["program_header_id"]);
ds.Tables["treeProgram"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "program_header_id is null";
tvMain.ItemsSource = ds.Tables["treeProgram"].DefaultView;
```

**ds.Tables["treeProgram"].DefaultView.RowFilter = "program_header_id is null";** was the magic line !